# Creating publish profile for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, dacpac, publish-profiles

I have an Azure SQL Database to which I am deploying using Azure DevOps pipelines. I want to specify a custom publish profile, but I am not successful in deploying the dacpac for the Azure SQL Database using a publish profile generated by Visual Studio 2019.

Can someone guide on how to go about creating a publish profile for Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

Within Visual Studio, you have a several source-control choices. GitHub is one of these source control solutions, and it provides a variety of advantages, including enhanced security features. Integrating various apps for a smooth CICD process, including as Visual Studio, GitHub, Azure DevOps, and Azure SQL Database, is a rising requirement for many companies on a path to modernize their data and infrastructure platform.

End-to-end solution for the following architecture flow to deploy a database from Visual Studio to an Azure SQL Database via a GitHub repository, which is then deployed via both an Azure DevOps Build (CI) and Release (CD) pipeline.

Here, is the link you column : [Configure CD of Azure SQL database using Azure DevOps and Visual Studio](https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/iac/200.2x-IaC-CDAzureSQLdbwithVSTSandVS.html)